# Hot pareve pot on fleishig (or milkhig surface)

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, food, meat-and-milk

If one's intention is to keep food pareve, is it permissible to put a hot pot (above yad soledes), full of pareve liquid onto a meat or dairy surface?

Does the pareve liquid become fleishig/milkhig? What if the hot pot is placed into meat or milk, mamash, like into a frying pan that was just used to fry meat and not cleaned?

Is there a bedieved opinion that it remains pareve?

Comment: If this is relevant to you, you should be sure to speak with your rabbi. Not everyone here knows what they're talking about, nor can they necessarily grasp the exact details of the case

Comment: @DoubleAA - thanks. I will be sure to speak with my Rabbi.

Comment: By what process would you imagine that the contents of the pot would become fleishig/milkhig?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok - let's say for example the hot pot was place on meat, mamash, such as a grill that has been used to make hamburgers and not been cleaned.

Comment: The question has been edited to differentiate between a clean surface (meat or dairy) and a non-clean surface with actual meat or dairy food/liquid.

Comment: Does the liquid taste meaty or milky?

Comment: @DoubleAA - let's say it tastes pareve, and only the outside of the hot pot came into contact with meat or milk.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question closely resembles the topic of two pots that are touching (see Rema in SA [YD 92:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.92.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and tangentially [93:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.93.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). By way of background: two pots are on the fire and touching, one dairy, one meaty. Even when boiling on the fire, their contents remain unaffected. As the Rema writes this is to be avoided *a priori*. If one of the pot is *parve* this is permitted *a priori* if the pots are clean at the point of contact.

However, if there is a liquid between the two pots, many write that the liquid will allow transfer of taste between the pots and render them and the food non-kosher.

Much of the above comes from R Yehuda Spitz's [article](https://ohr.edu/5167) on the topic, itself a summary of a forty page Hebrew essay he wrote on the topic (viewable [here](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=624838&pagenum=105)).

R Spitz applies this to your question of placing a hot pot on a meat/dairy surface.

> **If someone is cooking in a dairy pot and wishes to take it off the
> fire, and there is nowhere to place it except on the counter that is
> usually reserved for meat items, one may place it there. Nevertheless,
> since the issue is not as clear cut as it’s being presented, it is
> preferable not to do so, but rather one should place another layer of
> separation down first** (for example, a board, towel or aluminum foil)
> in order to satisfy all opinions.

In your question, the pot is parve which makes it even simpler to permit.

Your second question has too many variations (dry/meat or liquid/milk or frying pan; *lechatchila* or *bdieved*) to be answered in this format.

Of course, [consult your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146)
before implementing anything [you learn here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734).